# NSObject doesn't support encodeWithCoder?

Tags: ios

I'm using encoding for the first time in order to save data out of my app. The examples I have been looking at say to call `[super encodeWithCoder:coder];` for custom classes.

I have a class which extends `NSObject` but am getting the error msg below. Is this because `NSObject` is the base class and has nothing to encode?

> Receiver type 'NSObject' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'encodeWithCoder:'

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *) coder 
{ 
[super encodeWithCoder:coder]; //  <-------------------------ERROR

[coder encodeInt:noteIndex forKey:@"noteIndex"];
[coder encodeCGRect:cellRect forKey:@"cellRect"];
[coder encodeBool:noteOn forKey: @"noteOn"]; 
[coder encodeInt:note forKey:@"note"]; 
[coder encodeInt:velocity forKey:@"velocity"]; 
[coder encodeInt:channel forKey:@"channel"];
[coder encodeInt:releaseVelocity forKey:@"releaseVelocity"];
[coder encodeFloat:duration forKey:@"duration"];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's right, `NSObject` doesn't conform to `NSCoding`, so it doesn't implement `encodeWithCoder:`. Luckily, `NSObject` itself doesn't have any data to encode, so all you have to do is:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *) coder 
{ 
    [coder encodeInt:noteIndex forKey:@"noteIndex"];
    [coder encodeCGRect:cellRect forKey:@"cellRect"];
    [coder encodeBool:noteOn forKey: @"noteOn"]; 
    [coder encodeInt:note forKey:@"note"]; 
    [coder encodeInt:velocity forKey:@"velocity"]; 
    [coder encodeInt:channel forKey:@"channel"];
    [coder encodeInt:releaseVelocity forKey:@"releaseVelocity"];
    [coder encodeFloat:duration forKey:@"duration"];
}
```

And your `initWithCoder:` would just look like:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.noteIndex = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"noteIndex"];
        // and so on
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: do you have to now explicitly call 'initWithCode:(NSCoder*)decoder' when instantiating the object? if so what do you pass for 'decoder'?

Comment: nevermind, i tested and you don't have to explicitly call it, thanks!