# Crash on [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata, nsobject

I have NSDictionary with some keys.
One key has object of custom NSObject type class.

If I try to use  archivedDataWithRootObject: to get NSData from NSDictionary it crashes because of 1 key that has object of custom class.

I used NSCoding too for custom class's object key but got this error- '*** -encodeObject:forKey: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a concrete instance!'

How to solve this?

Comment: Please provide the crashlog.

Comment: All classes which are going to be archived must adopt `NSCoding`.

Comment: @iChris its -  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CustomClass encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105254000'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized selector sent to instance while archiving data (NSCoding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168753/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-while-archiving-data-nscoding)